# Using tuple as a key in a dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

In python I have a Random dictionary where I use
tuple as a key and each is mapped to some value.

Sample

```
Random_Dict = {
    (4, 2): 1,
    (2, 1): 3,
    (2, 0): 7,
    (1, 0): 8
}
```

example in above key: (4,2) value: 1

I am attempting to replicate this in Javascript world

This is what I came up with

```
const randomKeys = [[4, 2], [2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 0] ]

const randomMap = {}

randomMap[randomKeys[0]] = 1
randomMap[randomKeys[1]] = 3
randomMap[randomKeys[2]] = 7
randomMap[randomKeys[3]] = 8
randomMap[[1, 2]] = 3
```

I am wondering if this is the most effective way. I almost wonder if i should 
do something like holding two numbers in one variable so that way i can have a
dictionary in JS that maps 1:1. Looking for suggestions and solutions that are 
better

Comment: Note that the actual key for e.g. `[1, 2]` would be `"1,2"`; non-string keys are stringified.

Comment: what data structure do you want?

Comment: @NinaScholz in python i can have a dictionary that uses tuple as a key. That is what i am looking for

Comment: For things like this I usually find it better to create a class like "TupleKeyDict" with add/get methods to mimic the behavior you get in python.

Comment: *tuple* is no type of javascript. do you know an equivalent of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to *map* sets of 2 arbitrary values. In the following snippet the keys can be 'tuples' (1), or any other data type, and the values can be as well:

```js
const values = [
  [ [4, 2], 1],
  [ [2, 1], 3],
  [ [2, 0], 7],
  [ [1, 0], 9],
];

const map = new Map(values);


// Get the number corresponding a specific 'tuple'
console.log(
  map.get(values[0][0]) // should log 1
);

// Another try:
console.log(
  map.get(values[2][0]) // should log 7
);
```

> Note that the key equality check is done by reference, not by value equivalence. So the following logs `undefined` for the above example, although the given 'key' is also an array of the shape `[4, 2]` just like one of the Map keys:
>
> ```
> console.log(map.get([4, 2]));
> ```

(1) Tuples don't technically exist in Javascript. The closest thing is an array with 2 values, as I used in my example.

Comment: That looks, good, i am wondering why my question got downvoted. I did not ask anything wrong i even provided my solution.

Comment: I upvoted it, I had this exact same question for 3-tuples and this solution works!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```js
const randomKeys = {
    [[4, 2]]: 1,
    [[2, 1]]: 3,
    [[2, 0]]: 7,
    [[1, 0]]: 8
}
```

```js
console.log(randomKeys[ [4,2] ]) // 1
```

`[]` in objects property is used for dynamic property assigning. So you can put an array in it. So your property will become like `[ [4,2] ]` and your object key is `[4,2]`.

Comment: It's pretty hacky, but pretty cool nonetheless.

Comment: note that using values as object keys will stringify them, which could result in ambiguity if, e.g., your tuples contain strings with commas